# The method sendkeys(int) is undefined for the type WebElement

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using below code to give date as input:

```
Selecting Journey Date 
WebElement journeydate  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='lccp_day']")).sendkeys(20);
```

I believe issue is because of `sendkeys` is not accepting integers.

Please give suggestion what else I can use to give input as integers for any text box.

Using JAVA Compiler 1.8 and Firefox version 42.

Comment: Yes, `sendKeys` accept only string. You can convert your integer value to String, or just surround it with double quotes - `Selecting Journey Date WebElement journeydate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='lccp_day']")).sendkeys("20");` should workd fine.

Comment: use double '' to send integer value

Comment: sagar u got answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
//Selecting Journey Date 
WebElement journeydate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='lccp_day']")).sendkeys(20);
```

use this

```
//Selecting Journey Date 
WebElement journeydate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='lccp_day']")).sendkeys("20");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
String.valueOf(20);
```

to add your integer value as a String. 
And yes, judging  by the documentation sendKeys only accepts CharSequences.

Answer (score 0):

`SendKeys` Function accepts only string. so you need to type case your int to string before passing it to `Senkeys`.

Nick has shown you one way.

You can also perform same like below :-

```
     int i=0;
     String j = Integer.toString(i);
     driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(j);
```

OR

```
     Integer obj = new Integer(i);
     String str4 = obj.toString();
     driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(str4);
```

OR

```
     String str5 = new Integer(i).toString();
     driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(str5);
```

OR

```
     String str6 = new Integer(1234).toString();
     driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(str6);
```

Hope it will help you :)